# Tecdoc database query to show products from a category

Tags: mysql, database

i am trying to make a query to tecdoc database to show products, productid, productname.
I have the str_id which is the category_id and type_id which is the type of car but i can't find any way to make a query to show the spare parts that belong to the specific category and specific type of car.

Comment: How does it related to `MySQL`. Tag your question properly

Comment: I have imported to myslq. I couldnt tag as tecdoc because i dont have points!

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me, where did you find MySQL TecDoc database? I'm searching for PHP parser, because i have data only in text files, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try this:

```
SELECT
        count(LA_ART_ID) as total
        FROM
        LINK_GA_STR
        INNER JOIN LINK_LA_TYP ON LAT_TYP_ID = ".$TYP_ID." AND
        LAT_GA_ID = LGS_GA_ID
        INNER JOIN LINK_ART ON LA_ID = LAT_LA_ID
        INNER JOIN SUPPLIERS ON LINK_LA_TYP.LAT_SUP_ID=SUPPLIERS.SUP_ID
        WHERE
        LGS_STR_ID = ".$STR_ID."
```

Comment: Do you know which are the fields for productid, productname to show them instead of only a total number?